# Toggle Class combined with Spot.js changing perspective

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am busy with a project where images change perspective, following the mouse position, when the mouse is on the image.

**HTML**

```
    <a href=""><div class="one spot-area">
      <img class="thumbnail add1" id="extrema_outdoors_thumbnail" src="images/projects/ExtremaOutdoors/thumbnail/575x300.png" alt="extrema_outdoors_thumbnail">
    </div></a>

    <a href=""><div class="two spot-area">
      <img class="thumbnail add2" id="extrema_outdoors_thumbnail" src="images/projects/ExtremaOutdoors/thumbnail/575x300.png" alt="extrema_outdoors_thumbnail">
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href=""><div class="three spot-area">
    <img class="thumbnail add3" id="extrema_outdoors_thumbnail" src="images/projects/ExtremaOutdoors/thumbnail/575x300.png" alt="extrema_outdoors_thumbnail">
  </div>
</a>

<a href=""><div class="four spot-area">
  <img class="thumbnail add4" id="extrema_outdoors_thumbnail" src="images/projects/ExtremaOutdoors/thumbnail/575x300.png" alt="extrema_outdoors_thumbnail">
</div>
</a>
```

**the two variations i use**

```
  var spotAreaElem = document.getElementsByClassName("spot-area"),
      spotPerspectiveElem = document.getElementsByClassName("spot-perspective"),
```

**Toggle class**

```
$(".add1").hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("spot-perspective");
});

$(".add2").hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("spot-perspective");
});

$(".add3").hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("spot-perspective");
});

$(".add4").hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("spot-perspective");
});
```

So when i hover over the first images it works just fine. When i try to hover over a new images it seems like the `spot-perspective` did not toggle on the new images and on the old one.

But when i scroll and keep my mouse on the new images it does toggle on both images. after that the same problem occurs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[`$.toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#example-0) only a)adds or b)removes the class per function call. 
You need to manually call toggle again to remove the class after it was added.

The [mouseleave](https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) event can be used to detect when the mouse leaves.

```
// The function that will call the toggle. 
// This will add or remove the class based on if it present or not.
function toggleSpotPerspective(){
    $(this).toggleClass("spot-perspective");
}

$(".add1").mouseenter(toggleSpotPerspective).mouseleave(toggleSpotPerspective);
$(".add2").mouseenter(toggleSpotPerspective).mouseleave(toggleSpotPerspective);
$(".add3").mouseenter(toggleSpotPerspective).mouseleave(toggleSpotPerspective);
$(".add4").mouseenter(toggleSpotPerspective).mouseleave(toggleSpotPerspective);
```

Comment: I Still come across the same issue. I replaced my code with that of yours. Now is seems like they don't even toggle back. here is the page I am working on currently: http://boer-design.nl/v2_1/ , so you can see and maybe analyze what the problem may be.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I didn't test before. The problem was that the `mouseleave` wasn't working. Change the listener from `hover` to `mouseenter`
It seems `mouseleave` must be paired with `mouseenter`

Comment: Back to the same problem i had before :/ so weird. I am looking into new ways to do this. also because it looks like i have a lot of unnecessary code. Thank you for the help anyways !

Comment: Strange, it worked for me.
If you need to use that class for styling, I would suggest using the `hover` pseudo class instead.
[Hover Pseudoclass](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)
The browser will take care of adding/and removing the hover.